# Fragment save view state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate

I have some Fragment with this structure:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/control_panel"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/control_panel_icon">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/control_panel_icon_1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_control_panel_icon_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/control_panel_icon_2"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_control_panel_icon_2"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/control_panel_tv"
            android:text="@string/not_available" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And inside Fragment class i have `onSaveInstanceState` and `onActivityCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tv", panel_tv.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) 
        panel_tv.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("tv"));
}
```

So it solves saving the state of `TextView`.

Inside Fragment class I also setup which image to display with some function:

```
public void setIcon(boolean condition){
    if (condition) {
         control_panel_icon_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         control_panel_icon_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
         control_panel_icon_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         control_panel_icon_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to save and restore which image is currently displayed?

I know, what I'm shouldn't save entire widgets, but if I can save state of `RelativeLayout` will it restore all it's child's states?

Comment: In your fragment class, how do you decide which ImageView to display and which one to hide?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've updated the question.

Comment: You still need to provide more detail. What is "condition"? Do you really have a variable named `condition`? Or did you just replace your real code with that name?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's just some boolean. Updated again.

Comment: Then all you need to do is store that boolean during `onSaveInstanceState()` and read it back during `onActivityCreated()`. Note that saving the text in your TextView is unnecessary since the call to `super.onSaveInstanceState()` should automagically take care of that for you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice how can I do it, if I call `setIcon()` from some other class (so this boolean computes not inside Fragment class)?

Comment: You should store `condition` as a private variable in your fragment. You should also rename this variable to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your Fragment class, declare a private variable:

```
private boolean condition; // rename to something more descriptive
```

Now in `setIcon()` store the value:

```
this.condition = condition;
```

Finally save this to the bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
outState.putBoolean("condition", this.condition);
```

and read it in `onActivityCreated()`:

```
this.condition = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("condition");
this.setIcon(this.condition);
```

**Note**

You don't need to save the text from your `TextView`. The call to `super.onSaveInstanceState()` already takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can either save the `condition` in `outState` like below:

```
outState.putBoolean("condition", condition);
```

and then read it and update the image views

```
setIcon(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("condition"))
```

Or You can save the visibility state of the image views by `putInt` method:

```
outState.putInt("ic1", control_panel_icon_1.getVisibility());
outState.putInt("ic2", control_panel_icon_2.getVisibility());
```

and then restore the state:

```
control_panel_icon_1.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("ic1"));
control_panel_icon_2.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("ic2"));
```

Comment: I didn't know, I can save visibility status. Saving boolean seems like a better option though, thank you.