# How to store recyclerview data , while changing view (Fragments) via Bottom Navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, savestate, onsaveinstancestate

**I am following this question**

[how to store recyclerview data on onSaveInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233856/13413319)

I also found
[How to save state of view class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323199/how-to-save-state-of-view-class) and [Fragment save view state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022120/fragment-save-view-state).

**Context**

I give data in form of *`DataModel` (implements Parcelable)* to `recyclerview` in one of my Fragments.
using Bottom navifation and `ROOM DB` (to get and save Data).

**what I have done yet**

I used the code in first link and in my code. But I couldn't understand the fourth peace of code, which was used in there (I don't have a `response.boddy()`, Error).
Anyway every time changing the view `savedInstanceState = null` so the code is being redone.

**what I want or question**

I would like to not redo the work every time changing the view via bottom navigation?

what am I doing wrong, that data are not being saved in `savedInstanceState`?

**my Fragment view**

```
    private ArrayList<DataModel> data;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    currentContext = getContext();
    
    
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHome);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    this.data = new ArrayList<>();
    
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(data, currentContext, 1);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        
        // Retrieve the data you saved
        data = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("saved_data");

        //Call method to reload adapter record
        recyclerViewsaveInstance(data);
    } 
     else {
        
        //No data to retrieve

        dataAsynTask; //deleted, Basicly I get the data from DB, convert it to DataModel and give them to recyclerview.
    }

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i("savedInstanceState", "loading");
    
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("saved_data", this.data);
    
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}


public void recyclerViewsaveInstance(ArrayList<DataModel> dataset)
{
    this.data = dataset;
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataset, getContext(), 1);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);//notify adapter about the new record
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that the `savedInstanceState` bundle is `null` every time; this probably means that there's an issue in your `Activity` (or wherever it is that you create the `FragmentTransaction` to show your `Fragment`). Could you add that code to your question?

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps there's a misunderstanding about the concept of saving instance state. `onSaveInstanceState()` is called when the fragment is destroyed and recreated by a configuration change (like when you rotate your phone). If you are using bottom nav to switch to a different view and then switch back, that won't use `onSaveInstanceState()`. If you want your recyclerview data to be cached when you do this, you'll have to save it somewhere else (perhaps in the `Activity` that hosts the bottom nav and fragments).

Comment: I guess I am doing what you said (switching between views). Do you mean saving the hole recyclerview somehow?

Comment: I added what I had in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is to move your `AsyncTask` out to the `Activity` level, and have your `Fragment` ask the Activity for the `List<DataModel>`.

In your Fragment's `onCreateView()` method, instead of writing

```
this.data = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then checking `savedInstanceState` and conditionally executing an AsyncTask, you could write this:

```
this.data = ((MyActivity) getActivity()).getData();
```

Then, in your Activity, you'd implement this `getData()` method:

```
public List<DataModel> getData() {
    if (data != null) {
        return data;
    } else {
        // kick off AsyncTask here
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

When the AsyncTask finishes, have it update the Activity's `data` field and also have it notify the Fragment that new data is available. In the Fragment, you'd have a method like this:

```
public void onDataFetched(List<DataModel> data) {
    this.data = data;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

The end result of all of the above is that the `Activity` is now responsible for loading the data and for saving it. The `Fragment` doesn't know anything about the database or caching; it just knows to ask the `Activity` for the data whenever it is shown.

Since the `Activity` stays alive while you switch between Fragments with your bottom nav, it will successfully keep the data alive when you switch tabs.

Comment: feedback: This was Perfect. But I couldn't get my data from Asyntask (which was an interface methode called by Asyntask, after it was finished). I tried waiting for the result of Asyntask but It wasn't happening and the emulator was hanging too. I guess there is some problem with my Interface.                                           Any way I did what I was doing before, except a getter and setter methode in my "Activity" so if there was no data in Activity (which is just the first time), than I would get data from DB and save it in "Activity". After that data are always saved in "Activity".

Comment: `AsyncTask` was being used in 2020?